# merge dictionary based of condition match

Tags: python, django, dictionary, merge

I have a list of multi dictionary
currently looks like

```
result: [
        {
            "title": {
                "en": "Farm Added Successfully!"
            },
            "message": {
                "en": "Time to add Crops to your farm!"
            },
            "icon_link": {
                "en": null
            },
            "image_link": {
                "en": null
            },
            "message_code": 1002,
            "module": "Farm Added"
        },
        {
            "title": {
                "hi": "खेत सफलतापूर्वक जुड़ गया है!"
            },
            "message": {
                "hi": "अभी अपने खेत में फसल जोड़ें|"
            },
            "icon_link": {
                "hi": null
            },
            "image_link": {
                "hi": null
            },
            "message_code": 1003,
            "module": "Pending task today"
        },
        {
            "title": {
                "en": "Check out today's Tasks NOW!"
            },
            "message": {
                "en": "Tasks are important for your crop health!"
            },
            "icon_link": {
                "en": null
            },
            "image_link": {
                "en": null
            },
            "message_code": 1003,
            "module": "Pending task today"
        },
```

How can I merge the dictionary "title", "image", "icon" and "message", columns based on the condition when the "message_code" matches with the other dictionary "message_code"

and have the desired output as

```
"results": [
        {
            "message_code": 1002,
            "module": "Farm Added",
            "title": {
                "en": "Farm Added Successfully!",
                "hi": "खेत सफलतापूर्वक जुड़ गया है!"
            },
            "message": {
                "en": "Time to add Crops to your farm!"
                "hi": "अभी अपने खेत में फसल जोड़ें|"
            },
            "icon_link": {
                "en": null,
                "hi": null

            },
            "image_link": {
                "en": null,
                "hi": null
            }
        },
        {
            "message_code": 1003,
            "module": "Pending task today",
            "title": {
                "en": "Check out today's Tasks NOW!",
                "hi": "आज का कार्य अभी देखें!"
            },
            "message": {
                "en": "Tasks are important for your crop health!",
                "hi": "आपकी फसल के स्वास्थ्य के लिए कार्य महत्वपूर्ण हैं!"
            },
            "icon_link": {
                "en": null,
                "hi": null
            },
            "image_link": {
                "en": null,
                "hi": null
            }
        },
```

The code for this which I am using in Django gets API

```
        notification =[]
        input_dict = {}

        notification_data = get_notification_template(filter)
        notification_data = notification_data.replace({np.nan: None})

        for index, row in notification_data.iterrows():
            input_dict['message_code'] = row['message_code']
            input_dict['module'] = row['action_at']

            if row['message_code'] and row['action_at'] in input_dict.values():
                input_dict = {
                    'title': {row['language_code']: row['title']},
                    'message': {row['language_code']: row['message']},
                    'icon_link': {row['language_code']: row['icon_link']},
                    'image_link': {row['language_code']: row['image_link']},
                }

            else:
                input_dict = {
                    'message_code': row['message_code'],
                    'module': row['action_at'],
                    'title': {row['language_code']: row['title']},
                    'message': {row['language_code']: row['message']},
                    'icon_link': {row['language_code']: row['icon_link']},
                    'image_link': {row['language_code']: row['image_link']},
                }

            notification.append(input_dict)
```

Here get_notification_template is a function that gets the raw data from the database
and here I am creating a dictionary to show the data as per the required format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something likes this (the code can be optimized):

```py
input_dicts = [
   {'message_code': 1002, 'module': '1002', 'title': {'en': 'en'}, 'message': {'en': 'en'}, 'icon_link': {'en': 'en'}, 'image_link': {'en': 'en'}},
   {'message_code': 1002, 'module': '1002', 'title': {'es': 'es'}, 'message': {'es': 'es'}, 'icon_link': {'es': 'es'}, 'image_link': {'es': 'es'}},
   {'message_code': 1003, 'module': '1003', 'title': {'en': 'en'}, 'message': {'en': 'en'}, 'icon_link': {'en': 'en'}, 'image_link': {'en': 'en'}}
]
message_codes = {d['message_code'] for d in input_dicts}
output_dicts = []

for message_code in message_codes:
   dicts_with_code = [d for d in input_dicts if d['message_code'] == message_code]
   output_dicts.append({'message_code': message_code, 'module': dicts_with_code[0]['module']})

   for key in ['title', 'message', 'icon_link', 'image_link']:
      output_dicts[len(output_dicts) - 1][key] = {}
      for dict_with_code in dicts_with_code:
         for k, v in dict_with_code[key].items():
            output_dicts[len(output_dicts) - 1][key][k] = v
         
print(output_dicts)
```